# Are the new Disney-canon books aimed at a younger audience than before?

Tags: star-wars, disney

I haven't read any Expanded Universe books for a few years and none released since the Disney ownership though I've read a good deal in the past. I'd have said the majority of EU books were for adults (not explicit or anything but 300 or so pages and in the adult section of shops and libraries).

For those that have read some of the new material, has this continued or does it seem to be the case that Disney are now aiming their new (canon) EU novels at a younger audience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen a number of interviews indicating that the target audience for the NEU novels is still firmly adult:

> “One of the things that we’re excited about is: in addition to time to
>   expand the space, you’ll notice that the stories which involve Asajj,
>   or the Night Sisters, or some of the darker elements of Clone Wars,
>   they really push the boundaries of where you can go on an animated
>   show… And we think that a format like a book can really get inside
>   that psychology and space that might be a little too intense for an
>   animated show.” - [Pablo Hidalgo of the SW Story Group](http://screenrant.com/star-wars-clone-wars-season-7-ventress-novel/).

It's fair to say that a large proportion of the newest novels, specifically [those based on the Star Wars: Rebels franchise](https://catalog.clcohio.org/polaris/search/title.aspx?ctx=34.1033.0.0.13&pos=1) are firmly marketed at "[Juveniles](http://labs.libhub.org/worthingtonlib/portal/Rise-of-the-rebels-based-on-stories-by-Greg/KkQTqiga/)" (e.g. children and young adults) but the bulk (some 23 out of the 30 currently in the pipeline) are still aimed at the euphemistically titled ["*General*"](http://labs.libhub.org/worthingtonlib/portal/Heir-to-the-Jedi-Kevin-Hearne/cH3yQbjn/) audience.

Comment: That's good to know. Wouldn't blame them for steering clear of adult themes entirely but I'm glad they're going in this direction.